# GRPC android chat Cancelled before half close

Tags: java, android, grpc

I've developed and android chatting app, through the gRPC protocol, problem is, after I send the first message to the server, the server propagates the message to the available clients but then it runs in to this Exception: **"io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: cancelled before receiving half close"**

I've scoured the web for a hint at what could be wrong or a fix but I've got pretty much nothing useful.

This is my server class function that deals with the clients messages

```
    public StreamObserver<Messaging.Message> sendReceiveMessage(StreamObserver<Messaging.Message> responseObserver) {
        //  return super.sendReceiveMessage(responseObserver);
        //While you are on the inside of the chat the bilateral stream will be a continue one

        observers.add(responseObserver);

        return new StreamObserver<Messaging.Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Messaging.Message message) {
                //receiving data from client

                System.out.println(String.format("Got a message from: '%s' : '%s'", message.getMessageOwnerId(), message.getMessage()));
                observers.stream().forEach(o -> {
                    o.onNext(message);
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                 observers.remove(responseObserver);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                observers.remove(responseObserver);
            }

        };
    }
```

This is the protobuff for the messages

```
service MessagingService{

    rpc GetMessagingHistory(MessageHistoryRequest) returns (stream Message);
    rpc SendReceiveMessage(stream Message) returns (stream Message);

}
message MessageHistoryRequest{
    int32 chat_id = 1;
    int32 last_message_id = 2;
}
message Message{
    int32 message_id = 1;
    int32 chat_id = 2;
    int32 message_owner_id = 3;
    string message = 4;
}
```

and lastly the client side code:

```
private int CHAT_ID;

    private ImageView profilePicture;
    private TextView name;
    private Button sendButton;
    private EditText messageEditText;
    private RecyclerView chat;
    private MessageAdapter msgAdapter;

    private Vector<Messaging.Message> messages = new Vector<>();

    private ManagedChannel channel;

    private MessagingServiceGrpc.MessagingServiceStub stub;
    private StreamObserver<Messaging.Message> toServer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        initViews();
    }

    private void createStub(){
        channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("10.0.2.2",8080)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();

        stub = MessagingServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);


        toServer = stub.sendReceiveMessage(new StreamObserver<Messaging.Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Messaging.Message value) {

                msgAdapter.receiveMessage(value);
                Log.e("MYERROR",value.getMessageOwnerId() + " : " + value.getMessage() );
                msgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                //nothing

                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.e("Completed:","Why");
            }
        });
    }
    private void initViews(){
        profilePicture = findViewById(R.id.profilePictureChatMenu);
        name = findViewById(R.id.chatNameTextView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        CHAT_ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID",-1);
        name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("NAME"));
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendCommentButton);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.writingBarEditText);
        chat = findViewById(R.id.chat);
        chat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        msgAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),messages);
        chat.setAdapter(msgAdapter);

        createStub();

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Messaging.Message sentMessage = Messaging.Message.newBuilder()
                        .setChatId(CHAT_ID)
                        .setMessage(messageEditText.getText().toString())
                        .setMessageOwnerId(ApplicationController.getAccount().getId())
                        .build();
                toServer.onNext(sentMessage);

                messageEditText.setText("");
                msgAdapter.receiveMessage(sentMessage);
                msgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is just informing the server the client cancelled. There's nothing more for the server to do other than clean up resources.

The cancellation may have been triggered because of an I/O failure. The TCP connection may have been dead and sending a message on the connection exposed the fact the TCP connection died (TCP can only reliably detect breakages by performing a write).